# EclipseContext get beans of type

Tags: eclipse, dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have classes:

```java
@Creatable
@Singleton
public class Sample1 implements ISample {

}

@Creatable
@Singleton
public class Sample2 implements ISample {

}
```

How can i get all beans of type ISample from EclipseContext?

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse context does not support anything like this. All you can do is look for objects with a specific name (or specific class which is just converted to a name).

Additionally objects declared using `@Creatable` are not even created and added to the context until something actually uses them.